# How to store functions in Pinia store state?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, es6-promise, pinia

I'm using Pinia for state management in a Vue 3 project and I'm trying to create a custom alert component that can be invoked from any component in the application. To do this, I created a state and actions in the Pinia store, and I need to save the resolve and reject functions of a promise to use them later. However, when I try to save these functions, I get an error message stating that 'resolve/reject is not a function'. Upon printing the saved functions in the console, I noticed that I got proxy objects instead of functions. I was able to do this in Vue 2 using Vuex, but I haven't worked on front-end projects for a while. Forgive me if my question is too basic. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thankyou.

#### store.js

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useAppStore = defineStore('config', {
  state: () => ({
    alert: {
      data: {
        show: false,
        title: '',
        message: ''
      },
      config: {
        resolve: () => {},
        reject: () => {}
      }
    }
  }),
  actions: {
    showAlert(title, message) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.alert.data.show = true
        this.alert.data.title = title
        this.alert.data.message = message

        this.alert.config.resolve = resolve
        this.alert.config.reject = reject
      })
    },
    hideAlert(payload = null) {
      this.alert.data.show = false
      if (payload === false) {
        this.alert.config.reject(payload)
      } else {
        this.alert.config.resolve(payload)
      }

      this.alert.config.resolve = () => {}
      this.alert.config.reject = () => {}
    }
  }, 
  getters: {
    alertData: s => s.alert.data
  },
})
```

#### App.vue

```js
<template>
    <!-- layout, router view, etc -->

    <div class="alert-bg" v-if="alertData.show">
        <div class="alert-box" @click-outside="appStore.hideAlert(false)">
            <h2 class="alert-title">
                {{ alertData.title }}
            </h2>
            <p class="alert-message">
                {{ alertData.message }}
            </p>
            <button @click="appStore.hideAlert()">
                OK
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>
    import { useAppStore } from 'store.js'
    const appStore = useAppStore()

    const alertData = appStore.alertData
</script>
```

With this setup, I must be able to trigger the alert from any other component like this:

#### random-component.vue

```js
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
   <!-- form elemets -->
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { useAppStore } from 'store.js'
    const appStore = useAppStore()

    const submitForm = () => {
       callBackend.then(response => {
          if(response.success) {
             appStore.showAlert(
                'Success!',
                'Continue to home page?'
             ).then(() => {
                // router.push('/home')
             ).catch() => {
                // clear the form
             })
          }
       })
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. It should work they way you do it because Vue reactivity doesn't handle functions in a way you describe, and I can't reproduce this. This could be a bug that is specific to the versions you're using. A possible workaround could be `config: markRaw(...)` but it's not necessary here

Comment: That's how reactivity works in Vue3. In JavaScript, [functions are  objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). Any object stored in pinia's state (or in any other reactive object in Vue) is stored as a proxy. In simple terms, a proxy is a wrapper which keeps the original intact, but allows Vue to listen to when its props are read from or being written to, and this is how Vue can keep track of all the places where it's used and update them when the value changes.

Comment: That being said, maybe you should rephrase your question and explain what you're trying to achieve, instead of asking *"why is it like this?"* (There are several advantages to using proxies but knowing why won't help you solve the issue). I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way of achieving what you want, which could take advantage of the new reactivity API, if necessary. At a glance, it looks like you don't need reactivity here at all. But I can't advise based on what you shared so far.

Comment: I've included the context in which I'm using this setup. Hope it gives clarity on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: All you have to do in order to show an alert is to place it into an `alerts` array (and use that array in DOM, with a `v-for`). When you want it removed, you remove it from the array. Nothing from usage suggests you'd need to store promises. So you need an `alerts` array in state + `add` and `remove` actions which modify this array. You make your backend call, and add an alert. The alert component could have a timer which calls `remove` on the store after a timeout, with current alert's `id`.

Comment: If you want to store past alerts for being able to show them again, the `remove` action should move the alert into a `pastAlerts` array, instead of only removing it from `alerts`.